# Microphone doesn't work on a new Acer Nitro 16 with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, microphone

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 and my microphone from my wired headphones is not working. I tried the live version of fedora and nothing worked there either. I noticed that it gives me an error on startup:

Error when starting the laptop:

[image: Error when starting the laptop]

I've been trying for days to find a solution, but unfortunately I haven't found one, but the microphone from the bluetooth headphones works great.

Sound settings:

[image: Sound settings]

Microphone test:

[image: Microphone test]

For test I was using https://www.onlinemictest.com/ The laptop's built-in microphone doesn't work either.